# Porting AES Encryption from Java to Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, encryption, aes

I was tasked to port AES encryption from Java to Objective-C. I don't have access to the server's code where decryption took place. Using [FBEncryptor](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor), I've managed to do a simple AES encrypt of a string in Objective-C and decrypted it in Java and vice versa.

However, when I tried to send an encrypted data in Objective-C to server (which again, I don't have access to), the server sent me an "DER input not an octet string" fault. I figured that this code in Java, which I cannot replicate in Objective-C that is holding my path to success in the task.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKey);
String ivBase64 = Base64.encodeBytes(cipher.getParameters().getEncoded());
```

The `ivBase64` was sent to the server along with the encrypted String.

Any help in how to port this little part `cipher.getParameters().getEncoded()` to Objective-C is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that the `cipher.getParameters()` call returns an instance of `AlgorithmParameters`. This instance has a method [`getEncoded()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AlgorithmParameters.html#getEncoded%28%29) that has the following description:

> Returns the parameters in their primary encoding format. The primary encoding format for parameters is ASN.1, if an ASN.1 specification for this type of parameters exists.

Now, as far as I know, there is no such thing as a default ASN.1 DER encoding for an IV, but since an IV is basically a byte array, the most logical ASN.1 encoding is the OCTET STRING. When DER encoded, this ASN.1 type has a tag with value `04h` and then the length. The length will always the size of the IV directly encoded a single byte. The IV will always have the size of the block of the underlying cipher, which is always 16 bytes for AES.

So finally, you should be OK by prepending the bytes valued `04h` and `10h` to the IV.

Comment: Hi. I'm actually already found a sort-of solution (which is rather un-elegant) to this. I found out that by adding two bytes `{4, 16}` in front of the `iv` bytes would do the trick. With your solution, in addition to the two bytes `{4, 16}` added to the front, it also added an additional six bytes to the back and therefore decryption would fails.

Comment: OK, I can see what is happening. What you are seeing is a ASN.1 DER encoded structure containing the IV. I've never known about this weird feature; e.g. secret keys do not get the same treatment. So what you are seeing is the IV encoded as an OCTET STRING, which is an ASN.1 type with tag `04h` and then the length of the IV, encoded in a single byte, `10h` of course.

Comment: I'm a total newb when it comes to security and this is actually my first time dealing with cryptography library in my programming career. What I want to know is whether it's save to just assume that there's always that {4, 16} bytes added or there might be the case when it's going to bite me in the arse in the future?

Comment: The first byte `04h` consists of 3 bits defining the structure (all zero), then 5 bits defining the tag number, 4. This will always be the same. The second part will be the length of the IV. The length of the IV will always be the block size of the underlying cipher. For AES this will always be 16 bytes (but request the block size instead). Unless the block size is equal to or larger than 128 bytes, it may always be encoded as a single byte. This is a long explanation to say that you are safe :)

Comment: Not my favorite subject :) But I may have to read more materials about it in the very near future. Thanks for the insight.